# script in .json file allowing to deploy github-pages app in vanillaJS with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

How to write a deploy script in package.json file that will allow to deploy our vanillaJS with webpack app in github pages?

Such script for React apps looks like: "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
People are showing this example throught the web, but I don't find clear answear to webpack app in vanillaJS

https://github.com/vbv13/daftacademy-frontend_levelup-spring2019/tree/master/1st%20hangman

Welcome to look at app and package.json file